# qemuを起動しても何も表示されない

Tags: linux, macos, debian, qemu

qemu上でdebianを動かしたいのですがうまくいきません。
`brew install qemu`を実行してインストールし、debian9.5-amd64のisoをダウンロードした後、

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 os.img 6G
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -hda os.img -cdrom debian9.5-amd64.iso -boot d
```

としたのですが、Dockのところに`qemu-system-x86_64`と表示されるだけで新しいコンソールが開きません。
[image: Dock]

なぜでしょうか?

OS:macOS 10.13
CPU intel 64bit(x86_64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GUI なしでビルドされているのではないでしょうか。SDL または GTK が必要です。`qemu --help` (`qemu -h`) を実行すると `The default display is equivalent to` 行の次にデフォルトのディスプレイオプションが表示されます。

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -h |sed -n '/^Display options:/,$p' |head
Display options:
-display sdl[,frame=on|off][,alt_grab=on|off][,ctrl_grab=on|off]
    [,window_close=on|off][,gl=on|off]|curses|none|
-display gtk[,grab_on_hover=on|off][,gl=on|off]|
-display vnc=<display>[,<optargs>]
-display curses
-display none                select display type
The default display is equivalent to
    "-display sdl"
-nographic      disable graphical output and redirect serial I/Os to console
```

確認してみてください。

`qemu-system-x86_64` に `-display sdl` か `-display gtk` を追加で指定してみるとどうなりますか?

GUI が不要なら VNC やシリアルコンソールを利用するのもいいと思います。